# Exception after adding ProGuard to project

Tags: android, jsoup, proguard

I've added ProGuard to my project and got this error. I guess It can be Jsoup lib which I using to send POST and GET requests and parse responses.

There are no separate line that throwns this exception.

Can you help me to solve this problem with ProGuard?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.void initialiseParse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
                                        boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token)
        at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.ParseErrorList)(Unknown Source)
                                            boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token)
                                            boolean process(org.jsoup.parser.Token,org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState)
                                            void transition(org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState)
                                            org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilderState state()
                                            void framesetOk(boolean)
                                            void maybeSetBaseUri(org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                            org.jsoup.nodes.Element insert(org.jsoup.parser.Token$StartTag)
                                            org.jsoup.nodes.Element insert(java.lang.String)
                                            void insert(org.jsoup.parser.Token$Comment)
                                            void insert(org.jsoup.parser.Token$Character)
                                            boolean isElementInQueue(org.jsoup.helper.DescendableLinkedList,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                            void popStackToClose(java.lang.String[])
                                            void insertOnStackAfter(org.jsoup.nodes.Element,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                            void replaceInQueue(java.util.LinkedList,org.jsoup.nodes.Element,org.jsoup.nodes.Element)
                                            boolean inSpecificScope(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])
                                            boolean inSpecificScope(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[])
                                            boolean inScope(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])
                                            void insertInFosterParent(org.jsoup.nodes.Node)
        at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parseInput(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                   boolean isTrackErrors()
        at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parseByteData(java.nio.ByteBuffer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jsoup.parser.Parser)(Unknown Source)
                                     java.nio.ByteBuffer readToByteBuffer(java.io.InputStream,int)
                                     java.lang.String getCharsetFromContentType(java.lang.String)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse()(Unknown Source)
        at com.ThreeBoots.api.API.java.lang.Object userLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                  java.lang.Object userLoginFacebook(java.lang.String)
                                  boolean userLogout()
                                  boolean saveArticle(com.ThreeBoots.database.Article)
                                  java.lang.String loadPhoto(android.graphics.Bitmap)
                                  java.lang.String loadPhoto(android.widget.ImageView)
                                  java.lang.Object userSaveProfile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                                  java.lang.String sendRequest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])
                                  java.lang.String sendImageLoadRequest(java.lang.String,android.graphics.Bitmap)
                                  void processingBrands(org.json.JSONObject)
                                  java.lang.Object getListFromJSON(java.lang.Class,org.json.JSONArray)
                                  void insert(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)
        at com.ThreeBoots.api.API.java.lang.Object userRegister(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                  boolean sync()
                                  java.lang.String sendRequest(java.lang.String)
                                  void processingMaterials(org.json.JSONObject)
        at com.ThreeBoots.api.API.java.lang.Object userRegister(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                  boolean sync()
                                  java.lang.String sendRequest(java.lang.String)
                                  void processingMaterials(org.json.JSONObject)
        at com.ThreeBoots.asyncs.RequestAsync.java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.String[])(Unknown Source)
                                              void asyncSaveArticlePostExecute(java.lang.Boolean)
                                              void asyncRegistrationPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
                                              void startMainActivity()
                                              void startLoginActivity(android.app.Activity)
        at com.ThreeBoots.asyncs.RequestAsync.java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object[])(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 20 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.java.util.Map loadEntities(java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not add the parsing classes in your proguard to get obfuscate.
 keep it as it is. Write the below line in your proguard file

```
 -keep class yourclassname.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Proguard has skipped some of the files required, do this

```
-keep <your calss name>.** {
  *;
}
```

this will make sure proguard won't skip them while obfuscating